# OnCollisionEnter is not called in unity with 2D colliders

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I checked nearly every answer for this, but those were mostly simple errors and mistakes.
My problem is that OnCollisionEnter is not called even when colliding whith other rigidbody.

here is the part what does not get called:

```
 void OnCollisionEnter(UnityEngine.Collision col) {
        Debug.Log("collision!!!");
        foreach(ContactPoint contact in col.contacts) {
            //checking the individual collisions
            if(contact.Equals(this.target))
            {
                if(!attacking) {
                    Debug.Log("hitting target");
                } else {
                    Debug.Log("dying");
                    //engage death sequence
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Not even the "collision!!!" message appears. Do I understand the usage wrong, or did I forget something?

Comment: also the components attached to the object:
transform; sprite renderer; box collider 2D; circle collider 2D; enemy controller (script); rigidbody 2D; Animator;

Comment: Please [edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20567692/edit) to add this information, don't add it as a comment as it may be missed

Comment: The OnCollisionEnter won't be called if you're using a characterController. That has it's own collision method (I'm unable to look it up at the moment to link it).

Comment: okay, i managed to solve it. i needed to use the 2D equivalent. of collision. Unfortunately a cannot answer my own question.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Are you using 2D colliders and rigidbodies? If so use this function instead of **OnCollisionEnter**

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
    {
        Debug.Log(coll.gameObject.tag);

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure that the collision matrix (Edit->Project Settings->Physics) does not exclude collisions between the layers that your objects belong to.

[Unity Docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/LayerBasedCollision.html)

You also need to make sure that the other object has : collider, rigidbody and that the object itself or either of these components are not disabled.

Comment: I did, in the end i figured out that for 2D collisions you need to use the  OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) method.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour {
  void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {

    foreach (ContactPoint contact in collision.contacts) {
        Debug.DrawRay(contact.point, contact.normal, Color.white);
    }

    if (collision.relativeVelocity.magnitude > 2){
        audio.Play();        
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I do:

1. Make sure that object you wish to collide with target has non-kinematic rigidbody and mesh collider. My hitter object is a cube and just change its collider to mesh collider
2. On mesh colider inspector make sure you enable convex. Please see more mesh collider inspector detail [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-MeshCollider.html)

Now your OnCollisionEnter works. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

because you misstyped class name of parameter. this makes no error also not works.
eg:

```
OnCollisionEnter(Collider other) //this is wrong
OnCollisionEnter(Collision other) //this is correct
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need attach script to the same object, whose need detects the collision.