# Unity C# Collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I create a script for collision detection between two object. Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlayerMovement movement;

    void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collisionInfo)
    {
        if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Obstacle")
        {
            movement.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OnCollisionEnter is not called in unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20567692/oncollisionenter-is-not-called-in-unity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html, there's nothing wrong with the code that you've written.

A common reason that these method usages fail is because of the way you're handling movement (in this case) in your PlayerMovement script.

If you're modifying a transform's position directly through the position property for example, physics operations like collisions are not calculated. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html

Another common reason is that you don't have a rigidbody attached to one of the objects, so collision operations do not fire.

See the "Collision action matrix" section here:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html

Comment: Collision events will still be trigger if you update the transformation position directly,  however the built-in physic responses will not work. An example of this is OnCollisionEnter will still fire when 2 objects first collide as long as one has a rigidbody regardless of how it is moved.  Setting the transform.position directly, or even using transform.Translate will negate collision responses, 2 cubes will still collide but they will constantly attempt to penetrate each other causing jittering.