# How to check if a game object hits another object. When do i use triggers and when not?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I am making a simple 2D Game for my son to learn more about Unity. I have a topdown map where players and enemies walk around to pick up diamonds that appear at random intervals.

I use a Box Collider 2D, with "Is trigger" set to "no" to check if the player hits a wall. The wall has the same Box Collider 2D.

This means that the player can not run through the wall, which is good. However, my son wanted to hear a sound when the player hit the wall. I have no idea how to do that, since the "is trigger" is set to "no", so the OnCollisionEnter event does never start.

**So basically, what I want is to both prevent movement and set off a trigger.**

How should I fix this? Should I still set "Is trigger" to "yes" and work from there? Or is there a better way to implement this.

It should be so simple, but I just can't find out the best way to do it.

Comment: Unity will never call `OnCollisionEnter` in a script attached with a **Box Collider 2D**. You should use `OnCollisionEnter2D` instead. Does this answer your question? [OnCollisionEnter is not called in unity with 2D colliders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23235465/1092820)

Comment: Yes, thank you! And it was even simpler than i thought, this method is also called when 2 objects collide, but "Is trigger" is not active. Thanks a lot!